# Tricky problem about time and work

Tags: algebra-precalculus

today my 'Introduction to Mathematics' proposed the following problem.

Two painters spend 18 hours to paint a wall, how many hours will 4 painters spend in the same wall ?

She told us that they will spend 36 hours, I know how to get it but, it doesn't makes any sense to double the labor and spend more time. Is it right ?

Answer (score 1):

You're right. More workers means less time. Use the equation $Work=rate*time$. The amount of work to paint one wall, according to the first equation, is $2*18=36$ person-hours. Thus, for four workers, we have $36=4T$, which we solve to obtain $T=9$.

Answer (score 0):

The ratio is 
$$2:18$$
This is inverse proportionality, so the proportion is
$$2:18::x:4$$
Where $x$ is the number of hours the 4 painters take to paint the wall.

One thus has
$$8=18x\\
\implies x=\frac{4}{9}\mbox{hours.}$$